# Compare Date to List & Return Next Date In List

Tags: excel, vba, date, comparison

I am back with another one that I'm not quite sure how to do. As previously stated I am a beginner VBA programmer so a lot of things are not obvious to me.

Anyway what I am trying to do is:

- Have the user select a paygroup number from a dropdown cell (Done)
- Have the user insert the termination date in the format DD/MM/YYYY. If the paygroup is not selected then MsgBox with an error (Done)
- If everything is correct then compare the termination date with dates corresponding to that paygroup in another worksheet data table. Return the next cuttoff date AFTER the termination date entered as a MsgBox.

So far I have the following code:

Part of a greater worksheet event selection event

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("LastDayWorkedRange")) Is Nothing Then
       Call Cutoff2015
End If
```

Which calls this sub:

```
Sub Cutoff2015()

'If Paygroup has not been selected when entering termination date then error message and enable events
If Range("PayGroupRange") = "Please Select" Then
        MsgBox "Error: Please select Paygroup"
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    'If paygroup is selected then
    Else: Select Case Range("PayGroupRange")
        Case 118
        MsgBox "118"

        Case 113
        MsgBox "113"

    End Select

End If

End Sub
```

The cutoff dates are on a separate sheet called "Cuttoff Matrix" and are formatted with the paygroup number on the first row, and from the second row onwards is the dates in chronological order. The MsgBox's in the case's were put in to make sure it works. And up to this point it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a named range `TerminationDate` and dates in the sheet "Cuttoff Matrix" are put in ascending order, the following function would yield you the msgbox with the next date compared to the date put in `Range("TerminationDate")`.

```
Private Function Next_Date()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFoundPayGroup As Range
Dim cell As Range

'setting the range in Cutoff Matrix from A1 to the last not empty cell to right
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuttoff Matrix").Range("A1")
Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))

'finding identified PayGroup in the previously set range
Set rngFoundPayGroup = rng.Find(Range("PayGroupRange"), , xlValues, xlWhole)
'Looking downwards for the date bigger than termination date
For Each cell In Range(rngFoundPayGroup, rngFoundPayGroup.End(xlDown))
    If cell.Value > Range("TerminationDate").Value Then
        MsgBox cell.Value
        Exit For
    End If
    'If no date which is bigger, this msgbox appears
    If cell.Address = rngFoundPayGroup.End(xlDown).Address Then MsgBox "Next date not found"
Next

Set rngFoundPayGroup = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
End Function
```

Insert this function in the same module and change your previous rows `MsgBox "118"` and `MsgBox "118"` to `Call Next_Date`. Or even better, after inserting the function code, just delete this part of yours:

```
Select Case Range("PayGroupRange")
    Case 118
    MsgBox "118"
    Case 113
    MsgBox "113"
End Select
```

And use this instead: `Call Next_Date`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This option seems easier than doing it my way on a case by case basis. I've adjusted it slightly to work with my range names and such but I think I now need to work on the formatting of dates. I'm getting a mismatch error on this line:

If cell.Value > Range("LastDayWorkedRange").Value Then

Is it to do with the dates being in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: I think so. Use **Ctrl** + **;** (keyboard **Control** plus **semicolon**) on any cell in your workbook. You will get the date format that should be acceptable for your version of OS. So you would need to change the way you write dates into this Excel. Or do you really need the exact format that you defined?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I had to put .Cells (1, 1) before the .Value as the range covers multiple horizontal cells. I think it will work with a little more tweaking as I accidentally removed some lines.

Comment: Okay then. Happy to help. Can you mark this answer as the best for your situation?